# How do I reverse geocode Census Block group from 15 character FIPS Code to LATLONG?

Tags: geocoding, census

I know that the block group is a polygon but the Census Gazetteer files provide a lat/long for census tracts here - https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/geo/gazetteer-files.2010.html

Where can I get this for the census block group level?

The FCC provides an API that converts LATLONG to CENSUS BLOCK GROUP but Id like the reverse (https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/)- maybe I'm being vacuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which software you are using.

This can be accomplished by getting the centroids of the Census Block Group polygons.

Comment: Thanks - this question assumes software agnostics. Does that mean I open a shapefile of the block groups from here - https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2015&layergroup=Block+Groups and then calculate the centroid and then export  ? Im surprised someone has not already done this ..1

Comment: Sure. In ArcMap for instance, you would use Feature to Point and get the resulting points with lat/longs for the center of each Block.